# Using the qiskit_textbook Package

Tags: qiskit, programming

I've installed the qiskit_textbook package in Anaconda on Windows 10 using

```
pip install git+https://github.com/qiskit-community/qiskit-textbook.git#subdirectory=qiskit-textbook-src
```

based on the instructions at https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-prerequisites/setting-the-environment.html .

But I don't see any jupyter notebooks to open. How do you begin working with the qiskit tutorial notebooks? Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend trying the other way that they suggest, which is

```
git clone https://github.com/qiskit-community/qiskit-textbook.git
cd qiskit-textbook
pip install ./qiskit-textbook-src
```

You can find the juptyer notebooks with the content of the qiskit textbook in `qiskit-textbook/content`. There, you will find many different folders, each corresponding to a given chapter in the qiskit textbook.

If you would rather have access to the qiskit tutorials, you can access them on qiskit.org/documentation under the tab Tutorials, or download them locally with the command

```
git clone https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-tutorials.git
```

and in the `tutorials` folder you will find a folder corresponding to each category of tutorials.

Comment: Where can I find the qiskit-textbook/content folder?

Comment: If you go to the website https://github.com/qiskit-community/qiskit-textbook, under the code tab you'll see the "content" folder. If you want to have a copy of the "qiskit-textbook" code on your computer, you can press the green "Code" button and choose one of the options (the "Download Zip" option doesn't require using the terminal). Then if you navigate to the "qiskit-textbook" in your own file directory (for the "Download Zip" option, it should be in your "Downloads" folder for a MacOS), you can click into the folder and find the "content" folder.